# Trying to determine what percentage of visitors performed 1,2,3 or 4 of the listed activities among those who performed at least one

Tags: sql

The goal of my query is to determine the overlap between actions.
We have five specific actions across two different tables we are trying to measure.

Two of the actions are similar, but have different values in the table, but we want to consider those two specific actions as one.

table_1 - actions_1 column:
'action-a', 'action-b'

table_2 - actions_2 column:
'action-c' 'action-de', 'action-ed' (de and ed are the similar actions)

Both tables are have a column 'user_id' to tie together.

Question is, among users who've performed at least one action, what is the percentage of users who've completed 4, 3, 2, or just one action.

I'm able to determine overlap over single actions via consecutive left joins, but that only provides the answer for overlap for a single action, and doesn't provide a holistic answer. I'm also having trouble on how to tie 'action-de' and 'action-ed' together for analysis.

```
select count(distinct a.user_id)
from table_1 as a
     left join
           (select count(distinct user_id)
            from table_1
                  left join (... and so on for each action)
            where actions_1 = 'action-b'
            ) b
            on b.user_id = a.user_id
where actions_1 = 'action-a'
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of distinct users and how many activities they have done.  You could then perform statistics based on this data:

```
SELECT allactions.user_id, SUM(allactions.actions) FROM (

(SELECT table_1.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT table_1.actions_1) as actions
FROM table_1
GROUP BY table_1.user_id)

UNION ALL

(SELECT table_2.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT IF(table_2.actions_2 = 'action-ed', 'action-de', table_2.actions_2)) as actions
FROM table_2
GROUP BY table_2.user_id)

) allactions
GROUP BY allactions.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This counts the distinct actions by any user. Dividing by total users left as an exercise.

```
SELECT 
    distinct_action_count,
    count(*)
FROM
(
    -- user id and number of distinct actions they took
    SELECT
        table_1.user_id, 
        MAX(IIF([action-a]=1,1,0)))+ 
        MAX(IIF([action-b]=1,1,0))+ 
        MAX(IIF([action-c]=1,1,0))+
        MAX(IIF([action-de]=1,1,0))+ 
        MAX(IIF([action-ed]=1,1,0)) AS distinct_action_count
    from
        table_1
            FULL OUTER JOIN table_2
                ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
    GROUP BY
        table_1.user_id
) AS A
GROUP by 
    distinct_action_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an overall table with union statements, left joined it with the same overall table on user_id, excluding matching actions.

```
   select a.action_type, b.action_type, c.action_type, d.action_type, count(*)
from((
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_1
where action_type = action-a
union
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_1
where action_type = action-b
union
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_2
where action_type = action-c
union
select distinct user_id, case when action_type is not null then 'action-de'
from table_2
where action_type in ('action-de', 'action-ed')a
left join (
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_1
where action_type = action-a
union
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_1
where action_type = action-b
union
select distinct user_id, action_type
from table_2
where action_type = action-c
union
select distinct user_id, case when action_type is not null then 'action-de'
from table_2
where action_type in ('action-de', 'action-ed')b)
on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.action_type != b.action_type
```

Repeat left joins for c.action_type, d.action_type

You will get the count of all users who only completed 1 action by each different action, as b-d columns will be null.

You will get the count of all users who completed two actions, and the distinct actions they completed in columns a,b with null values for columns c,d.

And so on until you get a count of all users who completed all four actions.

The only issue is that this query doesn't de-dupe the duplicate combinations. ie a.action_type = action-a, b.action_type = action-b is the same as a.action_type = action-b and b.action_type = action-a. So you will get duplicate counts but with the actions listed in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select distinct user_id from table_1
    where actions_1 in ('action-a', 'action-b')
    union all
    select user_id from table_2
    where actions_2 in ('action-c', 'action-de', 'action-ed'
)
select distinct count(*) as num, count(*) / count(*) over () as pct
from data
group by userid
order by num;
```